R in VS Code: can't show variables Environment/Workspace
I recently started using VS Code for programming R but I always have issues with getting the environment/workspace to work. I need it to have an overview of my variables (and especially the data stored in them).
I never could find a button to straight away have the workspace but usually typing "View(variable)" would give me the menu. Now it just opens a window of actual R.
I have the extension "R for VSC" installed, so I am puzzled what I have to do to see my variables...
Please can someone help me?
I checked if the Github Copilot knows an answer and followed the instructions on this thread: Is there a way to view my active objects/files in Visual Studio Code similar to R Studio environment?

View() is working for me in VS Code (opens up a new pane with a view of the variable). I am using the Extension "R (R Extension for Visual Studio Code)" v2.8.4. How are you running your code? Pressing the run button or in an R Terminal?

So that is the thing that's confusing me. I tried again today and it worked just fine (same as you describe), but then sometimes it doesn't work without any apparent change. I had hoped that maybe there is another way to force VSC to open the R environment that I could use whenever "View()" doesn't work.
I use the same extension version.

Ah I see what you mean - that's incredibly annoying! I'm not aware of another way I'm afraid. Maybe someone else can help?
